# Currying function constructor

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'd like to know if it is possible to achieve this in javascript:

```
function Hello() { }

Hello.prototype.echo = function echo() {
  return 'Hello ' + this.firstname + '!';
};

// execute the curryed new function
console.log(new Hello()('firstname').echo())
```

Is it possible to curry `var o = new Class()(param1)(param2)(...)` ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: http://2ality.com/2017/11/currying-in-js.html

Comment: No. Don't do that.

Comment: Currying is an abstraction to have a partially applied function to be later aplied by different arguments. It's a functional thing. Do we really need partially constructed objects especially in a prototype based language..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48724664/1447675) of [georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989121/georg) with an array of the properties and a counter for assigning an arbitrary count of properties.

```js
function Hello() {
    var args = ['firstname', 'lastname'],
        counter = 0,
        self = function (val) {
            self[args[counter++]] = val;
            return self;
        };
    Object.setPrototypeOf(self, Hello.prototype);
    return self;
}

Hello.prototype.echo = function echo() {
    return 'Hello ' + this.firstname + ' ' + (this.lastname || '') + '!';
};

console.log(new Hello()('Bob').echo());
console.log(new Hello()('Marie')('Curie').echo());
```

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```js
function Hello() {
    let self = function (key, val) {
        self[key] = val;
        return self;
    };
    Object.setPrototypeOf(self, Hello.prototype);
    return self;
}

Hello.prototype.echo = function echo() {
    return 'Hello ' + this.firstname + this.punct;
};

console.log(new Hello()('firstname', 'Bob')('punct', '...').echo())
```

Comment: Very clever, but I just need `console.log(new Hello()('Bob')('...').echo())`. Is it doable and is there a way to keep static methods ?

Comment: How would the function know that Bob is a firstname?

Answer (score 1):

In your code `new Hello('Bob')` does not return a function, but an object that has an `.echo()` method.

`function Hello(firstname) {}` is a contructor function that returns an object when instantiated with `new`.

```js
// constructor function expecting 1 argument
function Hello(firstname) {
  this.firstname = firstname;
}

// attach a method to the constructor prototype
Hello.prototype.echo = function() {
  return 'Hello ' + this.firstname + '!'; // the method can use the contructor's properties
};

// new Hello('Bob') returns the object, and you can call the .echo() method of that object
console.log(new Hello('Bob').echo())
```